# How to load a data set into Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

When loading a dataset into Jupyter, I know it requires lines of code to load it in:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets   import base

 # Data files
IRIS_TRAINING = "iris_training.csv"
IRIS_TEST = "iris_test.csv"

# Load datasets.
training_set =  base.load_csv_with_header(filename=IRIS_TRAINING,
                                         features_dtype=np.float32,
                                         target_dtype=np.int)
test_set = base.load_csv_with_header(filename=IRIS_TEST,
                                    features_dtype=np.float32,
                                    target_dtype=np.int)
```

So why is ther error `NotFoundError: iris_training.csv`
still thrown? I feel as though there is more to loading data sets on to jupyter, and would be grateful on any help on this topic

I'm following a course through AI adventures, and dont know how to add in the .csv file; the video mentions nothing about how to add it on.

Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7oolm0jU8I&list=PLIivdWyY5sqJxnwJhe3etaK7utrBiPBQ2&index=3

Comment: "iris_training.csv" is a file that is supposed to sit in your local directory. Make sure that the path to it is correct.

Comment: So where is it meant to be saved? And is something missing on the code for it to be saved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you either need to use file's absolute path i.e **C:\path_to_csv\iris_training.csv** for windows and for UNIX/Linux **/path_to_csv/iris_training.csv** or you will need to place the file in your notebook workspace i.e directory that is being listed in your Jupyter UI which can be found at **http://localhost:8888/tree** Web UI. If you are having trouble finding the directory then just execute below python code and place the file in the printed location

```html
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
print(cwd)
```

Answer (score -1):

## Solution A

if you are working with python you can use python lib pandas to import your file .csv using:

```
import pandas as pd
IRIS_TRAINING = pd.read_csv("../iris_training.csv")
IRIS_TEST     = pd.read_csv("../iris_test.csv")
```

## Solution B

```
import numpy as np
mydata = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=",")
```

Read More About
[python-pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)
Read More About
[python-Numpy](https://numpy.org/)